# Modal popup with cookie.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to implement a modal popup on my homepage that displays on the first page visit only and expires after a set amount of time. I am currently using cookie.js to do so and I have a JSfiddle (here:https://jsfiddle.net/yaLsdahk/68/) that works to perfection. However, when I try to copy the code over to my homepage, it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody offer assistance?

Here's my html markup and script:

```
<div id="init-modal-wrapper">
<div class="opening-modal-title"> A little heads up... </div>
<div class="close_box_6">
<div class="icon-font-25 alignment" data-icon="&#xe0ab"></div>
</div> 

<div id="horizontal_bar" class="alignment"> </div>

<div id="popupfoot" class="alignment"> 
<div id="typeface" class="init-modal-text">STUFF!</div>
</div>

</div>  

<div class="init-modal-overlay"></div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($.cookie('init_modal_1') == null) {
    $.cookie('init_modal_1', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
var delay=4000;
setTimeout(function(){
$("#init-modal-wrapper").stop().animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "slow");
$('.init-modal-overlay').fadeIn("slow",function(){});

}, delay);

};

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? We have almost nothing to go on here.

Comment: It should be showing a modal 4 seconds after the page loads, but it doesn't. Nothing happens.